# FactoryGirl creating an extra object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

My factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    content 'bla bla bla bla bla'
    user
  end

  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "johnsmith#{n}" }
    password '123'

    factory :user_with_comments do
      ignore do
        comments_count 5
      end

      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:comment, evaluator.comments_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Comment do
  let(:comment) { Factory.create :comment }

  describe "Attributes" do
    it { should have_db_column(:content).of_type(:text) }
    it { should have_db_column(:user_id).of_type(:integer) }
    it { should have_db_column(:profile_id).of_type(:integer) }
  end

  describe "Relationships" do
    it { should belong_to(:profile) }
    it { should belong_to(:user)    }
  end

  describe "Methods" do
    describe "#user_name" do
      it "Should return the comment creater username" do
        user         = Factory.create :user
        binding.pry
        comment.user = user
        binding.pry
        comment.user_username.should == user.username
      end
    end
  end
end
```

On the first binding.pry, **User.count** returns 1 as expected. But on the second binding.pry, **User.count** returns 2. My question is, why the **comment.user = user** assignment creates a new user record ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your let for `comment` calls `Factory.create :comment`. In the factory for `comment`, it calls the association for `user`.

So when you use your let, it makes a comment object and a user object and connects them. Then, you override that user when you set `comment.user=user`.